# Rails not connecting on port 3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not able to connect to localhost:3000 (when I try, it directed me to Google SERP - server log shows the following) but localhost:3001

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.1 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.5.1-p57), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

when sudo nano /etc/hosts, it showed 127.0.0.1 localhost

127.0.0.1:3000 works though

Where did I go wrong?

This happened for the first time for me.

When I tried

```
    wget http://0.0.0.0:3000
    --2018-09-24 01:46:21--  http://0.0.0.0:3000/
    Connecting to 0.0.0.0:3000... failed: Connection refused.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try start rails server with:

```
$ bundle exec rails server -b 0
```

Then go to http://localhost:3000